# RecyclerViewが2つあるとAndroid 6.0でのみ高さが正しくない

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerItem1" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerItem2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Other Layouts... -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

このようなlayoutで、全てのアイテムをスクロールせずに表示したいと思っています。
Android6.0のみ、全てのアイテムがスクロールせずに表示される場合とされない場合があります。
今のところ表示される場合とされない場合の決定的な違いがわかりませんが、同じリストの組み合わせでは必ず毎回同じ症状が再現されます。

２つのRecyclerViewを使っているので高さの計算と、親のレイアウトの計算の順序などの問題があるのではないかと思いますが、どこを調べていくことで解決できそうかアイデアありませんか？
よろしくお願いします。

Android Studio: 2.2.2
ライブラリバージョン: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1

Comment: どうやら、画面の最下部の位置にRecyclerViewがまたぐ形でおかれていると、その先の描画がされず高さが縮まってしまうようです。この現象をどのように解消したらよいのか・・・・。

Answer (score 1):

自分もRecyclerViewの高さをwrap_contentにしても、子ビューが全て入るだけの領域が確保されない現象がありました。
その際にはScrollViewをandroid.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollViewに変更したところ期待通りの動作になりました。